# Is it possible to combine fields in a SQL query into one resulting field?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I want to select the following from my table:

Hello James, your address is 1 Some Road.

using a query like this:

```
SELECT ('Hello ' + name + ', your address is ' + address) AS result FROM Users
```

The `Users` table has two varchar(50) fields called `name` and `address`. Is this possible using a simple, single line of T-SQL as above? When I run the query above it returns **-1 records affected.**

Comment: _When I run the query above it returns -1 records affected._ I think this gives you the answer you are looking for.

Comment: this should actually work no problem, just tried it in my mssql, you're sure you have more than 1 record in your table?

Comment: There are 600 records in the table, however, my example was a bad one, the fields im working with are in fact of type `int` which is why I think its not concatenating correct?

Comment: @Jimbo If the data is not a string, then you can to cast it to a varchar

Comment: if conversion is the problem, CAST( yourNumber as varchar(5) ) might do the trick.

Comment: If anyone can point out why this is "Off-topic" I'd be grateful :) The question appears to be in line with the offended rule: `Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions` Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

Apologies for the bad example - the data types I was working with are in fact `int` and that was why the concatenation wasn't working - they needed to be CAST first (thanks @bluefeet)

So this worked:

```
SELECT ('Hello ' + CAST(name AS varchar) + ', your address is ' + CAST(address AS varchar)) AS result FROM Users
```

Comment: Make sure you use a length on the `varchar`

Comment: @bluefeet Is that for good practice or is there a practical reason? Thanks

Comment: see this -- https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length

Answer (score 2):

It depends which RDMBS you are using, syntax may be different. Here are some examples:

MySQL: `SELECT CONCAT('Hello ',name) FROM USER`

Oracle: `SELECT 'Hello ' || name  FROM USER`

SQL Server: `SELECT 'Hello' + name  FROM USER`

Comment: SQL Server as mentioned in the tag

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, its SQL Server 2012

Comment: no you didn't, didn't forget I mean :)

Comment: he forgot to mention and I get two downvotes? How nice.

Comment: did you look in the question's tags?

Comment: they were not there when I opened this question, I was trying to help.